# Show model-dependent variable in R with Keras in Viewer

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, rstudio

I want to plot the value of a scalar weight in the Rstudio viewer (where also the loss and metrices are plottet) over the epochs. Is this possible? I already wrote a callback

`print_weights = callback_lambda(on_epoch_end=function(batch,logs) tf$print(model$trainable_variables[[1]]$value()))`

but it is not displayed in the viewer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `self$add_metric(variable,name="name_var")`
where the variable is used does the job